# Implementing video play in the app objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


     MPMoviePlayerController *player =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player.view setFrame: self.viewVedio.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.viewVedio addSubview: player.view];
    // ...
    [player play];


and 

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    [player play];
```

I am implementing simple video play in the view controller , but It's not worked. It can see only blank black screen . Please help to fix the issue. I have tried with both `MPMoviePlayerController` which is deprecated now and `AVPlayerLayer`.
My code goes like this .both code are not working please help me on the issue . I see just a black screen displayed in the view

Comment: is your deployment target 9.0?

Comment: This is the simplest example of video Player Please Refer this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_audio_video.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlVideo]
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];

        [moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
        [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
        [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [moviePlayer play];
        moviePlayer.backgroundView.hidden = YES;

        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```